# why the table view cells are messed up after refreshing some rows?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, afnetworking

I am using `UITableView` to list some images from Internet. So i use `AFNetworking's` `setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:`methord, when the image is downloaded, i need to do some process then display. In order to refresh the processed image i use

```
[wTableView beginUpdates];
[wTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[wTableView endUpdates];
```

in the success block. It seems this works when first time loaded, but when i scroll the tableview, the rows are messed up, also one row is disappeared and **its easy to crash in the `[wTableView endUpdates];` method**. what's wrong with this method?
The related code snippet is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"cell";

    CouponTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CouponTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
    }
    [cell prepareForReuse];

    NSArray *coupons = [mCoupons objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    CouponDB *couponDB = [coupons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *thumbLink;
    if (couponDB) {
        [cell.textLabel setText:couponDB.couponInfo.company];
        [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:CELL_LABEL_FONT_SIZE]];
        [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Expires:%@",couponDB.couponInfo.deadline]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        thumbLink = [self thumbLink:couponDB.couponInfo.imgURL];
        [cell setNeedsLayout];

        if (couponDB.redeem_status) {
            UIImageView * __weak imageView = cell.imageView;
            CouponTableController * __weak table = self;
            UITableView *__weak wTableView = mTableView;
            [cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbLink]] placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                imageView.image = [table crossedImage:image];
                @synchronized(wTableView){
                    [wTableView beginUpdates];
                    [wTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                    [wTableView endUpdates];
                }

            } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"cell imageview load error:%@",error);
            }];
        } else {
            [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbLink] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_cover.jpg"]];
        }

    }

    if (![cell.backgroundView isKindOfClass:[CouponTableCellBackgroud class]]) {
        cell.backgroundView = [[CouponTableCellBackgroud alloc] init];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

the first time the table is loaded(no scroll) is like this:
[image]

when you scroll down and up the table rows are messed up, which is like below:
[image]

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why dont you use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) instead. It is simple to use and provides caching as well.

Comment: @Amar I use AFNetworking for most network issues,And i think for this issue AFNetworking is enough :). i think the key problem is when the image is downloaded, how to notify tableview to update the related cell.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, instead of reloading the cell. Declare a weak pointer to the cell

```
__weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell; 
[cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbLink]] placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
            weakCell.imageView.image = [table crossedImage:image];
            [weakCell setNeedsLayout];                

 } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"cell imageview load error:%@",error);
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"YourResuseIdentifier";

      CouponTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    else
    {
        for (UIView *subview in cell.contentView.subviews)
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }


    NSArray *coupons = [mCoupons objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    CouponDB *couponDB = [coupons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *thumbLink;
    if (couponDB) {
        [cell.textLabel setText:couponDB.couponInfo.company];
        [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:CELL_LABEL_FONT_SIZE]];
        [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Expires:%@",couponDB.couponInfo.deadline]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        thumbLink = [self thumbLink:couponDB.couponInfo.imgURL];

        if (couponDB.redeem_status) {
            UIImageView * __weak imageView = cell.imageView;
            CouponTableController * __weak table = self;
            UITableView *__weak wTableView = mTableView;
            [cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbLink]] placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                imageView.image = [table crossedImage:image];

                [wTableView beginUpdates];
                [wTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                [wTableView endUpdates];


            } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"cell imageview load error:%@",error);
            }];
        } else {
            [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbLink] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_cover.jpg"]];
        }

    }

    if (![cell.backgroundView isKindOfClass:[CouponTableCellBackgroud class]]) {
        cell.backgroundView = [[CouponTableCellBackgroud alloc] init];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    else
    {
        for (UIView *subview in cell.contentView.subviews)
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
it not reuse the cell every remove views in cell,it not reuse the cells

Comment: @NANNAV For preventing reuse of cells.

Answer (score 0):

I change the load image code to

```
UIImageView * __weak imageView = cell.imageView;
CouponTableController * __weak table = self;
[cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbLink]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_cover.jpg"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                imageView.image = [table crossedImage:image];
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"cell imageview load error:%@",error);
   }];
```

Only **add one placeholder image** and remove the tableview updates. then it refresh cells automatically.